# Android edittext caps lock

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is there a way to make keyboard for an `EditText` input only cap letters ?
I tried every possible way I found and nothing seems to work

I tried

```
android:inputType="textCapCharacters"

android:digits=" ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ " 

android:textAllCaps="true"

etSearch.setInputType(0x00001001);

etSearch.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS);
```

with all this (and more) it's like nothing is set, the EditText still receives every character

Comment: Your android:digits attribute should take care of it. Are you sure you have your layout xml right, and you're referring to the correct View?

Comment: Addendum: android:digits _and_ android:inputType="textCapCharacters". If you use just digits, your keyboard might not open with "caps lock" on, and anything typed in lower case will not be accepted because of the digits attribute.

Comment: `android:inputType="textCapCharacters"` always work for me

Comment: thank you guys, i have no idea why this is not working, "etSearch.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS);" this worked only in the GS3, tested on both Galaxy Ace and GS4 and didn't work, some kind of sorcery

Comment: @ramaral do you get the keyboard with uppercase ? if so, in wich devices  have you tested ?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy Gio and Samsung Tab2 tablet

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a way to do that. The best thing you can do is every time you're getting the input from the editText convert it to upper case letters, user will see both lower case and upper case letters when typing but after that everything will be upper cased. Here's the code:

```
editText.getText() .toString() .toUpperCase();
```

this returns a string with upper case letters so use it like that:

```
myString = editText.getText() .toString() .toUpperCase();
```

Comment: thanks but this doesn't help, because this is done transparently I need to show in the UI that the user in working with uppercase chars